# How to display in console the result of ROCK, PAPER, SCISSOR GAME Javascript

Tags: javascript

I`m currently stuck with a rock, paper, scissors game in javascript.
I need to  display in console something like this:
Computer choice: “Rock”
User choice: “Paper”
User wins!

How can I implement this in the code below.

```js
                let userSelection = userPlay();
        function userPlay() {
                let random = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
            return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        }
        let computerSelection = computerPlay();

        function computerPlay() { //computer generates a random answer.
            let random = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
            return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

        }
        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) { //plays a round of the game.
            if (playerSelection === "rock") {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "Draw!";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "Computer wins!";
                } else {
                    return "User wins!";
                }
            } else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "User wins!";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "Draw!";
                } else {
                    return "Computer wins!";
                }
            } else {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "Computer wins!";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "User wins!";
                } else {
                    return "Draw!";
                }
            }
        }
                
        console.log(playRound(userPlay, computerSelection));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have swapped the position of function calls for better readability. Idea is to store the result of each function call into a variable and print it.

```js
        function userPlay() {
                let random = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
            return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        }
        function computerPlay() { //computer generates a random answer.
            let random = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
            return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

        }
        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) { //plays a round of the game.
            if (playerSelection === "rock") {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "Draw!";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "Computer wins!";
                } else {
                    return "User wins!";
                }
            } else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "User wins!";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "Draw!";
                } else {
                    return "Computer wins!";
                }
            } else {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "Computer wins!";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "User wins!";
                } else {
                    return "Draw!";
                }
            }
        }
        
        var userChoice = userPlay();
        var computerSelection = computerPlay();
        var result = playRound(userChoice, computerSelection)
        console.log("user's choice", userChoice);
        console.log("computer's choice", computerSelection);
        console.log("Result is", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm too late for an answer but I have refactored the code a bit (it can be refactored a bit more I think, but I'll let you do that).

```js
                        let playerSelection = getNumber();
    let computerSelection = getNumber();

    function getNumber() { //computer generates a random answer.
     let random = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
        return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    }
    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) { //plays a round of the game.
        let message = '';
        let random = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
        
       let playerSelectionIndex = random.indexOf(playerSelection);
        let computerSelectionIndex = random.indexOf(computerSelection);
        switch (true) {
            case(playerSelectionIndex == computerSelectionIndex + 1):
            // Scissors beats rock
            case((playerSelectionIndex + 2) == computerSelectionIndex):
                message = 'You Win';
                break;
            case (computerSelectionIndex == playerSelectionIndex):
                message = 'Draw';
                break;
            default:
                message = 'You lose';
                break;
        }
        return message; 

    }
            
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```